# Erro no Envio de formulário Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Olá, preciso de uma ajuda, quando eu tento enviar ele exibe a menssagem com sucesso e dps exibe a menssagem de erro ao enviar, quando entro no modo dev do navegador e vejo a contato.blade.php ele aparece aquele erro la em cima de utf-8 e nao faz o envio, quando eu tiro o java script ele envia o email mas pq estou em localhost

Esse é o erro que aparece quando você envia os formulários de contato:

```
{message: "Caracteres UTF-8 malformados, possivelmente codificados incorretamente",…} mensagem: "Caracteres UTF-8 malformados, possivelmente codificados incorretamente" exceção: "InvalidArgumentException"
```

Uma parte do formulário html:

```
   @csrf
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-center col-12">
                    <div class="form text-left">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input name="nome" type="text" class="form-control form-input"
                                                    placeholder="Nome">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control form-input"
                                                    placeholder="E-mail">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Controller com uma função para envio:

```
$form = $request->all();

        Mail::to(['****@*****.***'])
            ->send(new SendMail($form,'Formulário de Contato'));
        if (Mail::failures()) {
            echo '0';
            exit;
        }
        echo '1';
```

O modelo enviaMail:

```
class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($form,$subject)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
        ->from('****','Fale Conosco')
        ->subject("Fale Conosco | ".$this->subject)
        ->view('emails.contact',$this->form);
    }
}
```

arquivo javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                alert('Enviando')
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Menssagem enviada com sucesso');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Erro ao tentar envia o E-mail');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

O que devo fazer? Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Olá @leo burik seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Seja específico na sua pergunta, fale sobre o erro, mas também diga o que deve corrigir para podermos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Olá entao quando eu tento enviar ele exibe a menssagem com sucesso e dps exibe a menssagem de erro ao enviar, quando entro no modo dev do navegador e vejo a contato.blade.php ele aparece aquele erro la em cima de utf-8 e nao faz o envio, quando eu tiro o java script ele envia o email mas pq estou em localhost

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque esse seu comentário acima da mensagem de erro, assim os especialistas da comunidade terão um parâmetro melhor para te ajudar.

Comment: esta bem, obrigado !